# Using "ViewState" in RxSwift/MVVM

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

This question is very broad but I'm not sure which aspect of it I should focus on.  I have a goal to abstract away the recurring patterns of my screens such as errors, loading, empty data.  The views that represent these states will not change much between the many screens I have.  Perhaps they could be parameterized to allow that flexibility (e.g. `showError(message: "404")`).

I liked [this article](https://medium.com/@johnsundell/using-child-view-controllers-as-plugins-in-swift-458e6b277b54) as a method of encapsulating the reusable UI aspects of this.

But it appears to work in an imperative context.  So I have an API call and I can `showError` and in the response I can `hideError`.  Thats all fine.

Now I use an RxSwift/MVVM approach where each screen binds to inputs and outputs.  And I like to simplify the state my screen knows about by using a "View State" concept.

As you can see in this snippet, I can reduce a lot of logic a single Observable that the view renders.

```
let getFoos: (String) -> Observable<FooViewStateState> = { query in
            fooService.perform(query)
                .map { results in
                    if results.isEmpty {
                        return ViewState.noResults(query: query)
                    } else {
                        return ViewState.matches(query: query, results: results.map { $0.name })
                    }
                }
                .startWith(ViewState.searching(query))
        }
```

The problem is that by using an enum `ViewState` its now unclear to me how to use the imperative API from before "showLoading / hideLoading ... showError / hideError, etc..." when I'm switching on the cases of this enum.  If the ViewState Observable emits `.loading` I'd have to hide the error screen, hide the empty screen, etc..